# PHP "EMPTY" constant name

Tags: php

Could you please tell me why this code throws a parse error if the name of the constant is EMPTY, but if I change it to EMPTY2 or SUBSTR it does work.

```
    define('EMPTY', '');

    if (empty(EMPTY)) {
       echo 'hello world';
    }
```

Comment: then use `MYEMPTY` :p

Comment: _It is possible to define() constants with reserved or even invalid names, whose value can (only) be retrieved with constant(). However, doing so is not recommended._ http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 5):

Because, as stated in this Quora answer, [PHP function names are case-insensitive](https://www.quora.com/Is-PHP-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive), so `EMPTY` collides with the built-in function `empty()`.

PHP manual mentions this in a small note right after [Example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-134) in the subsection about User-defined functions:

> **Note:** Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.